# I want to replace a certain text with an image in a word document via interop.word

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

So I want to know whats wrong with my code, Im trying to replace a text field with an image.
Specifically, I want to replace "{no}" with uncheck.jpg and "{yes}" with check.jpg.I know I am missing something but I dont know what it is. When I debug it, it gives an exception with  aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/check.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, "{yes}"); Type mismatch.
 Please help in short notice.

```
try
    {
        File.Copy("C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/cover.docx", "C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/temp/" + txtname.Text + " " + txtsur.Text + ".docx", true);
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        Word.Application wordApp = new Word.ApplicationClass();
        Word.Document aDoc = null;
        object filename = "C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/temp/" + txtname.Text + " " + txtsur.Text + ".docx";
        if (File.Exists((string)filename))
        {
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = false;
            wordApp.Visible = false;
            aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing,
            ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing);

            aDoc.Activate();
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{isim}", txtname.Text);
            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{soyisim}", txtsur.Text);

            if (imgbtnyes.ImageUrl == "~/check.jpg" && imgbtnno.ImageUrl == "~/uncheck.jpg")
            {

                aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/check.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, "{yes}");
                aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/uncheck.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, "{no}");
            }
            else if (imgbtnno.ImageUrl == "~/check.jpg" && imgbtnyes.ImageUrl == "~/uncheck.jpg")
            {
                aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/uncheck.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, "{no}");
                aDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\\Users/can.KUMSAATI/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/WebSites/WebSite4/check.jpg", ref missing, ref missing, "{yes}");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('Seçiniz');</script>");
            }
            aDoc.Save();
            KillProcess(procname);
            if (aDoc.Saved)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + txtname.Text + " " + txtsur.Text + ".docx");
                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/temp/" + txtname.Text + " " + txtsur.Text + ".docx"));
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        else
            Response.Write("File does not exist.");
        KillProcess(procname);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.Write("Error in process.");
    }
}
private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application wordApp,
        object findText, object replaceText)
{
    object matchCase = true;
    object matchWholeWord = true;
    object matchWildCards = false;
    object matchSoundsLike = false;
    object matchAllWordForms = false;
    object forward = true;
    object format = false;
    object matchKashida = false;
    object matchDiacritics = false;
    object matchAlefHamza = false;
    object matchControl = false;
    object read_only = false;
    object visible = true;
    object replace = 2;
    object wrap = 1;
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase,
        ref matchWholeWord, ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike,
        ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format,
        ref replaceText, ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                ref matchDiacritics,
        ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);'
```

Comment: Where is the error? It probably has something to do with the file paths being wrong

Comment: file paths are correct Im checking it, the code creates a word file and modifies the "{}" spaces with texts and images at least the file is being created and text fields are being modified when I delete the image replacement lines. Its just the image replacement I couldnt find out.